# ParallelDo issue with SQLExecute (SQLite)

Tags: parallelization, sql

This code run as expected if I use Do[...], but if I use instead ParallelDo[...], as in the code bellow, the SQL INSERT statements seems to be completely ignored.

In both cases, the filename is correctly printed (Print[file]), as well as d[[1]] (Print[d[[1]]]) as obtained from importing the file.

I am using Mathematica 10.4 and SQLite 3120200.

Q: Where is the issue here with the "Parallelized" code.

```
(* ::Package:: *)

Needs["DatabaseLink`"];

extractFeatures[filename_String]:=StringExtract[filename,"."->{2,-2}]/.s_String:>StringReplace[s,{"chr"->"","gotypes_"->""}]//ToExpression

insertBlob[file_String]:=Module[{conn,cons,chr,startIndex,code,data},
    {chr,startIndex}=extractFeatures[file];
    data=Import[file,"MX"];
    Print[file," imported"];
    conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite","/home4/j/sl/sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3120200/cancerg.db"]];
    Do[
        Print[d[[1]]];
        code =ExportString[d[[2]],"MX"];
        SQLExecute[conn,"INSERT INTO mx_tb (cons,chr,mx) VALUES (`1`,`2`,`3`)",{d[[1]],chr,code}]
       ,{d,data}];
    CloseSQLConnection[conn]
]

slDir="/home4/j/sl/";
g1000Dir=slDir~~"/data/1000";
SetDirectory[g1000Dir];
files=FileNames["*.mx"];
files=Sort[files,OrderedQ[{extractFeatures[#1],extractFeatures[#2]}]&];
ParallelDo[insertBlob[file],{file,files}]
```

Comment: `insertBlob` and `extractFeatures` are not defined in the parallel kernels. You should also `ParallelNeeds` the `DatabaseLink` package. Also missing is `ParallelEvaluate[SetDirectory[...]]` (each kernel has its own directory), in which case you will also have to define the variables `slDir` and `g1000Dir` in the kernels (see `DistributeDefinition`).

Comment: You should learn to think about parallel kernels as *completely independent* Mathematica sessions.

Comment: @becko $insertBlob$ and $extractFeatures$ both seems to be known to the kernels since filename $file$ is printed right, the correct file is  imported and the right $d[[1]]$ content printed, which depend as well on $extractFeature$. $ParallelNeeds$ did not work either, but now I got $ParallelDo$ working by introducing $Needs$ into $insertBlob$ before the $OpenSQLConnection$ statement, I expect for other ways, might be better.